# Setting Tab XPosition/YPosition correctly for form fields using Aspose.Net PDF Kit

Tags: .net, pdf, tabs, aspose

My PDF forms may contain signature/initial/date fields at various locations within the pages throughout the PDF document. I having issues dynamically setting each of the tab's XPosition/YPosition for my various form signature/initial/date fields. I am using Aspose.NET PDF API to get the x/y position of the form field within the PDF/Page, which yields the corresponding form field's Rectangle properties of lower left X,Y and upper right X,Y. These are supposed to give the position of the rectangle of the form field within the PDF page.

When I use either of these values I get from the Aspose.Net PDF API (lower left x,y or upper right x,y), the result in the DocuSign signing process is a tab/Sign Here positioned higher in the particular page than expected.

Does anyone have any experience with using Aspose.NET PDF form field rectangle x,y positions and setting the tab X/Y positions correctly? I am thinking that it is a DPI issue between the PDF and what DocuSign is expecting perhaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower left / upper right values are usually relative to bottom left corner of the page. It is possible that DocuSign expects values that are relative to top left corner of the page. 
Try subtracting the lower left / upper right y from the page height and use the result with DocuSign.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, this worked perfectly. You were correct - Here is the code that I used to calculate: yPos = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Pages[pageNum].Rect.Height - (interactiveField.Rect.URY + (interactiveField.Rect.URY - interactiveField.Rect.LLY)));

Answer (score -1):

```
yPos = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Pages[pageNum].Rect.Height - 
    (interactiveField.Rect.URY + 
    (interactiveField.Rect.URY - interactiveField.Rect.LLY)));
```

That worked for me.